# How to block email addresses in Thunderbird?

Tags: lubuntu, thunderbird, email

I have two email id's in Thunderbird one for `mary@my_email.com` the other for `tom@my_email.com`.
Every day I receive many spam emails that have addresses such as `sexygal@my_email.com`, `yourhighness@my_mail.com` etc etc.

Can I set a filter so that I only receive emails addressed to tom and to mary?

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can block a sender in Thunderbird by following suggestions [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/blocking-sender) or [here](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_block_unwanted_emails_in_thunderbird.html). I should add that this post is more suitable for [Mozilla support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird).